# .net core authentication using System.DirectoryServices

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to implement active directory authentication in my .net core application. 
When I read https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089 this mentions that out of the box System.DirectoryServices is not supported by .net core. So as per the post I added preview for System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.

After adding this how do I create a ldap connection. I am not able to create a one as it always returns null or gives object reference error.

I try to create connection as:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xx.com", username, password);
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you connecting to LDAP server or Active Directory server ?

Comment: As per my experience `PrincipalContext` is smooth for Active Directory, but not LDAP servers.